# Does State of Decay have Sandbox mode for the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, state-of-decay

I read that State of Decay has a sandbox mode.  Is this mode available on the Xbox One version?  If so, how do I access it?

[Reference from Undead Labs](http://undeadlabs.com/2013/07/news/enter-sandbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be State of Decay: Breakdown.  It's DLC you can buy where you start as random survivor (more available after certain achievements) and you can build up your survivors and homebase, you then have an additional task where you can move to a harder level of difficulty

Spoiler below, perhaps?

> There is an R.V. you need to find (a marker will be provided), you then need to repair it with supplies.  After that you can select only a few survirors to take with you.